# Mobile Verification with Missed call API - Android

Tags: android, verification

What is the low cost mobile verification API for android through missed call.
Cognalysis is one are there any reliable APIs available?

Comment: welcome to SO. Take a quick overview of SO at http://stackoverflow.com/tour . And before posting these types of question make sure to google it once

Comment: there are plenty of options available you can choose as per your requirements. Twilio and Sinch are popular for mobile number verification.